# Why is my model not being saved? (CakePHP 2.x)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I have a User table which is related to a table UserDetail. 
`User(#id, name, password)`
`UserDetail(#id, address, city, user_id)`

`UserDetail.user_id` is a foreign key linked to `User.id`.

Here is the form where I put my address if I want to add a new one :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('UserDetail');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('address', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('city', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Modifier', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

My controller :

```
public function customer_edit($id = null){
    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid user details');
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->request->data['UserDetail']['user_id'] = $id;
        if ($this->User->UserDetail->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Done!');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error.');
        }
    } 
}
```

And I always has the flash 'Error'. `if ($this->User->UserDetail->save($this->request->data))` doesn't work. And if I take a look to `$request->data` with DebugKit, I have all input datas.

Adding a new record doesn't work... Where is the problem?

Thanks.

EDIT :
Here is my UserDetail class :

```
class UserDetail extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric')
            ),
        ),
        'address' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'allowEmpty' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'city' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'allowEmpty' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'user_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
            ),
        ),
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => true,
            'counterScope' => array(),
        )
    );
}
```

And the UserDetail post data content :

**>UserDetail**

**id**

**address** test

**city** test test

**user_id** 19

Comment: It looks like it might be failing validation. Check what `$this->User->UserDetail->->validationErrors` contains if it fails to save.

Comment: Probably not validating. Try debuging UserDetail->validationErrors

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I obtain `array()`, seems to be empty

Comment: Please post the content of `UserDetail` under _DebugKit / Request / Post data_ after submitting the form once. Also, let us know if you have implemented UserDetail::beforeSave(). Other stuff such as table names, model class names, validation rules and relationships would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't want to set a validation rule for the primary key Model::id. However, if you do so, you must enforce it only when you are updating a record, and not when you are creating it (it's empty in such cases).

Try rewriting your validation array as follows:

```
public $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'on' => 'update' //don't enforce rule on create
        ),
    ),
    'address' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),
    ),
    'city' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),
    ),
    'user_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

BTW, having `'rule' => array('notEmpty')` and `'allowEmpty' => false` in the same rule is redundant. You can delete the latter.

Having said this, I recommend that you rethink your view and action, as they don't seem to perform as I think you expect.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advices. I'll separate edit and add address. It works with `'on' => 'update'` but I'll change the process. Thanks.